# best way to migrate a database?

Tags: sql-server-2014, azure-sql-database

I currently have a on-premise SQL Server 2014 High-Availability cluster.
I will setup a active geo-replication/auto failover group in Azure.
I need to do a one-time data migration---Should I use Azure Data factory?
Also, how do i ensure compatibility with the legacy Sql Server 2014 ?

Thanks, Peter

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to use Microsoft [Data Migration Assistant](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53595). It will perform an assessment of your on-premises databases first, then it allows you to migrate the database to Azure SQL Database. This tool is very user friendly. It's very easy to migrate a database to Azure with this tool.